iOS App Submission: Asset Validation Failed for Missing Icons and Invalid Version Number
I’m encountering multiple validation errors while trying to submit my iOS app to the App Store. Below are the specific errors I’m receiving:

Missing CFBundleIconName:
Asset validation failed Missing Info.plist value. A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'Bundle'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key.

Missing Required Icon Files for iPhone/iPad:
Asset validation failed The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0. Asset validation failed The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0.

Invalid Version Number:
Invalid Version. The build with the version “1.6.4” can’t be imported because a later version has been closed for new build submissions. Choose a different version number. This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.1.3] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.6.4].


I’ve already tried the following:

Added CFBundleIconName to my Info.plist file.

Checked that all required icon sizes are present in the asset catalog.

Updated the version number in CFBundleShortVersionString.


Despite these fixes, the same errors persist. How can I resolve these issues?
Steps I’ve Taken:

Added CFBundleIconName to Info.plist:
<key>CFBundleIconName</key> <string>AppIcon</string>
(I’ve ensured the name matches the icon set in the asset catalog.)

Verified the Asset Catalog:

All required icons (120x120 for iPhone, 152x152 for iPad) are included in the AppIcon set.

Icons are .png files and the exact sizes required.



Updated Version Number:

Changed CFBundleShortVersionString to 1.6.5 (higher than the previously submitted 1.6.4).


Cleaned the Project:

Deleted the Derived Data folder.

Cleaned the build folder via Product > Clean Build Folder.



Validated Locally:

Re-archived the app and tried validating it again.



note: also my app icon it 1024pt and it's iOS Universal
